# Can images from a user's photos library moved to the Hidden folder from a third party application?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Photos Framework provides an API to move to folders. But, is there a way to change the status of an image to hidden, and thereby move it to the iOS Hidden folder and hiding it from the main photo gallery?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save some data privately so no other app could access it you probably need to save it into the app data container. This could be a `/Documents` folder for example. Take a look at `FileManager` class to work with file system.

> Use this directory to store user-generated content. The contents of this directory can be made available to the user through file sharing; therefore, his directory should only contain files that you may wish to expose to the user.
>   The contents of this directory are backed up by iTunes and iCloud.

[File system documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW12)

Comment: Thank you for the response, @inokey. The issue I have is that I want to help the users manage their library by hiding some of their photos based on some logic. Would this be possible? I'm not finding a way to do this.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phasset/1624773-hidden) flag? Edit: Sorry! It's read-only. So I guess there's no option with the API.

Comment: I did. Like you said, it's read-only :/ Thanks for your help.